# TeamCity checkout only the branch with the latest changes

Tags: svn, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

it's possible to define a VCS Checkout rule like `+:PathToSvn/branches => .` and check out only the branch with the latest changes?
So you don't know the name of the branch beforehand.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use configuration parameter in Checkout rules, e.g. `+:PathToSvn/%branches% => ..`. %branch% parameter should be defined when the build started. For more details see the [section](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Defining+and+Using+Build+Parameters+in+Build+Configuration#DefiningandUsingBuildParametersinBuildConfiguration-UsingBuildParametersinBuildConfigurationSettings) in TeamCity doc.